# How can I create a JS variable from a value out of a json data file?

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

Json file:

```
[
   {
    "id":"40",
    "name":"Holliday",
    "firstname":"Billy",
    "company":"Blues"}
]
```

I get some data from a json file that is filling my columns in my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example3').DataTable( {
                 "ajax": {
                 "url": "data.json",
                 "dataSrc": ""
                },
                "columns": [
                   { "data": "id" },
                   { "data": "name" },
                   { "data": "firstname" },
                   { "data": "company" },
                  ]
              } );
       } );
```

Now I need to add a custom column that combines text and the ID from the json file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example3').DataTable( {
                 "ajax": {
                 "url": "data.json",
                 "dataSrc": ""
                },
                "columns": [
                   { "data": "id" },
                   { "data": "name" },
                   { "data": "firstname" },
                   { "data": "company" },
                   {"data":null,className: "action","defaultContent":"The id of this person is" + id}
                  ]
              } );
       } );
```

So I need to know how to define the variable ID to put it into my text. I tried

var id = data.id;

but it is not working

Comment: You mean ***"defaultContent": "The id of this person is " + data.id***?

Comment: @Esko Yes, actually yes.

Comment: Without seeing the json nobody can help you. plz post your json.

Comment: @Khaleel Ok one second

Comment: update your question with the json

Comment: @Khaleel updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other mentions, use the `column.render` callback, but use it right :) Target `full` (or the third argument) to get the rows complete JSON item, and set the columns `data` property to `null` :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 data: data,
 columns: [
   { data: "id", title: 'id' },
   { data: "name", title: 'name' },
   { data: "firstname", title: 'firstname' },
   { data: "company", title: 'company' },
   { data: null, 
     title: 'combined',
     render: function(data, type, full) {
       return 'The id of '+full.firstname+' '+full.name+' is '+full.id
     }
   } 
 ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pa1ps1yz/**

Answer (score 1):

**defaultcontent** is static and therefore cannot possibly access the data.

Instead try using **render**

**USAGE:**

```
.
.
{ "data": "company" },
{
    sortable: false,
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {                     
    return '<span class="action">The id of this person is '+data.id+'</span>';
         }
}
```

Comment: Tested. The result is: `"The id of this person is "+data.id`

Comment: @Jarla Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example3').DataTable( {
                 "ajax": {
                 "url": "data.json",
                 "dataSrc": ""
                   },
                  "columnDefs": [
                      {
                     "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                         return 'The id of this person is' + data;
                     },
                     "targets": 4
                     },
                ],
                "columns": [
                   { "data": "id" },
                   { "data": "name" },
                   { "data": "firstname" },
                   { "data": "company" },
                   { "data": "id" },
                  ]
              } );
       } );
```